# (?:) regular expression Python

Tags: python, regex

I came across a regular expression today but it was very poorly and scarcely explained. What is the purpose of `(?:)` regex in python and where & when is it used?

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to be working. Why is that?

```
word = "Hello. ) kahn. ho.w are 19tee,n doing 2day; (x+y)"
expressoin = re.findall(r'(?:a-z\+a-z)', word);
```

Comment: Read the docs! http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: And what did you expect to match? Perhaps you wanted to match `[a-z]\+[a-z]` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`re` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> ```
> (?:...)
> ```
>
> A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever
>   regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring
>   matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or
>   referenced later in the pattern.

Basically, it's the same thing as `(...)` but without storing a captured string in a group.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('(?:foo)(bar)', 'foobar').groups()
('bar',)
```

Only one group is returned, containing `bar`. The `(?:foo)` group was not.

Use this whenever you need to group metacharacters that would otherwise apply to a larger section of the expression, such as `|` alternate groups:

```
monty's (?:spam|ham|eggs)
```

You don't need to capture the group but do need to limit the scope of the `|` meta characters.

As for your sample attempt; using `re.findall()` you often **do** want to capture output. You most likely are looking for:

```
re.findall('([a-z]\+[a-z])', word)
```

where `re.findall()` will return a list tuples of all captured groups; if there is only one captured group, it's a list of strings containing just the one group per match.

Demo:

```
>>> word = "Hello. ) kahn. ho.w are 19tee,n doing 2day; (x+y)"
>>> re.findall('([a-z]\+[a-z])', word)
['x+y']
```

Answer (score 0):

`?:` is used to ignore capturing a group.

For example in regex `(\d+)` match will be in group `\1`

But if you use `(?:\d+)` then there will be nothing in group `\1`

Answer (score 0):

It is used for non-capturing group:

```
>>> matched = re.search('(?:a)(b)', 'ab') # using non-capturing group
>>> matched.group(1)
'b'

>>> matched = re.search('(a)(b)', 'ab') # using capturing group
>>> matched.group(1)
'a'
>>> matched.group(2)
'b'
```